# Can't install laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, virtualbox

I'm trying to get laravel set up on my Windows 8.1, but keep running into errors. Can anyone advise what's going wrong here and how I can sort it? I have vagrant and virtualbox setup as required. Thanks.

```
C:\Users\Robin>vagrant box add laravel/homestead
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    box: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/homestead
==> box: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v0.2.2) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading:
    https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.2.2/providers/virtualbox.box
    box: Progress: 100% (Rate: 582k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
The box failed to unpackage properly. Please verify that the box
file you're trying to add is not corrupted and try again. The
output from attempting to unpackage (if any):

x ./box-disk1.vmdk: Write failed
x ./box.ovf: Write failed
x ./Vagrantfile: Can't create '\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\Robin\\.vagrant.d\\tmp\\vagrant-box-add-temp-
20150112-14824-106nj0l\\Vagrantfile'
bsdtar.EXE: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that the download of the box was not successful completely, but the file was "corrupt". You can retry the command multiple times, because vagrant resumes the download from previous failed download:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead
```

Comment: Here in my system it was the same issue as @PHZ.fi-Pharazon said, I had to restart the download several times. Another suggestion is to temporarily disable your anti virus.

Answer (score 0):

try this command :

`vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead`

please tell me if it worked or i'll delete it (i'm not able to comment)